# Model relationship many to many with attribute on relational entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying something very simple. At this point I have three models:

```
Player >> PlayerMatch >> Match

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :goals_team_a, :goals_team_b
  has_many :PlayerMatches
  has_many :Players, :through => :PlayerMatches
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :password_confirmation, :password, :user
  has_many :PlayerMatches
  has_many :matches, :through => :PlayerMatches
end

class PlayerMatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :match_id, :player_id, :team
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :match
end
```

The model PlayerMatch is the join entity. In each Match a player plays, he can be on team A or team B, that is why I made that attribute team on PlayerMatch.

**How can I set that value team for each match?** I want to do something like:

```
p = Player.new
//set players attributes
m = Match.new
//set match attributes

p.matches << m
```

Now I just want to set his team on that specific match.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the models you have set up, you can do something like this:

```
p = Player.create
m = Match.create
pm = PlayerMatch.create(:player => p, :match => m, :team => 'Team')
```

If you want the PlayerMatch automatically created as in your example, you can retrieve it afterwards and set the team at that point:

```
p = Player.create
m = Match.create
p.matches << m

pm = p.matches.where(:match_id => m.id).first
pm.update_attributes(:team => 'Team')
```

Unless you are saying an individual player can play different matches for different teams though, it seems like you may want a Player to belong_to a Team instead.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059238/creating-controllers-and-views-for-a-has-many-through-relationship-in-rails-3) also has some info related to this question.

Comment: thank you, nice response...i will think more about the model and try different ways to do this

Comment: @Gabriel Souza Please accept the answer if it solved your problem or answered the question.